# Getting demo data into core-list

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

The polymer website gives this example for use of core-list:

```
<core-list data="{{data}}" height="80">
  <template>
    <div class="{{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}">List row: {{index}}</div>
  </template>
</core-list>
```

But nowhere is explained how I would get some simple test data into this list using html/js. All of the examples invlove creating a custom element, but I'm still trying to get my head round the framework and would like to just put some simple data into a list!

Could anyone explain to me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one answer to this question based on how you are using `core-list`. Since you asked about *simple test data*, I assume your markup is in your main document (`index.html`), in which case an easy way to do it is like so:

```
<core-list height="80">
  <template>
    <div class="{{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}">List row: {{index}}</div>
  </template>
</core-list>

<script>
  document.querySelector('core-list').data = [{"index": 0}, {"index": 1}, {"index": 2}];
</script>
```

http://jsbin.com/jasus/1/edit

Fwiw, you are supposed to be able to do it by supplying JSON in the `data` attribute to `core-list`, but that element [isn't properly type-hinting](https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/26) that property to be object-valued. When that issue is fixed, you could write it this way:

```
<core-list height="80" data="[{'index': 0}, {'index': 1}]">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with basic static databinding with Polymer.

Also you **must** define the height of the `core-list` element or else nothing will show up.

http://jsfiddle.net/4kp81x5m/2/

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-list/core-list.html">
    
<my-list-test></my-list-test>
<polymer-element name="my-list-test">
  <template>
    <style>
      .mylist {
        height: 540px;
      }
    </style>
    <core-list data="{{mydata}}" class="mylist" flex>
      <template>
        <div layout horizontal>
          <div>Index {{index}} to name {{model.name}}</div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </core-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
        mydata: [{name: "1"}, {name: "2"}, {name: "3"}, {name: "4"}]
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's necessary to point out that core-list doesn't bring it's own height with it. You **must** set the height as Victor mentioned.